# Draw mesh edge / map a graph to a mesh

Tags: graphs-and-networks, plotting, mesh

I am doing a "force density" method to generate a mesh under certain load.

The original mesh is like this:

[image: Original Mesh]

Then, I generate a IncidenceMatrix from the graph for further matrix transformation and get the points of these vertex under certain load.
Those points are plotted here:

[image]

The question is, these points have lost the original edge relationship of the original graph...

I'd like to also draw the edges between those points, as the original one.
"Mesh-> Full", or "Mesh->All" do not give the right plot...

How can I do?